# Split dataframe of customers on whether they used a credit card at least once

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to split a dataframe in two based on, for example, whether a customer has used a credit card for a purchase at least once.

The example dataframe is organized as follows:

```
data = {
    'purchase_id'=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
    'customer_id'=[1,1,2,2,3,3,3],
    'used_card'=[True, True, False, False, True, False, False]
}
```

The ideal output would be a dataframe containing all rows where the customer used a card, and a dataframe containing all rows for customers who have never used a card at all. I am just throwing out rows with used_card==False if the customer has used one before at least once.

output:

```
purchases_with_card = {
    'purchase_id'=[1,2,5],
    'customer_id'=[1,1,3],
    'used_card'=[True, True, True]
}

purchases_by_customer_with_no_card = {
    'purchase_id'=[3,4],
    'customer_id'=[2,2],
    'used_card'=[False, False]
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
purchases_with_card = data[data['used_card']]
print (purchases_with_card)
   customer_id  purchase_id used_card
0            1            1      True
1            1            2      True
4            3            5      True
```

And:

```
mask =~data['used_card']&~data['customer_id'].isin(data.loc[data['used_card'],'customer_id'])
purchases_by_customer_with_no_card = data[mask]
print (purchases_by_customer_with_no_card)
   customer_id  purchase_id used_card
2            2            3     False
3            2            4     False
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, however this isn't exactly what I want. purchases_by_customer_with_no_card shouldn't contain any rows from a customer who is in purchases_with_card. Edit: I'll give that a shot